# how to update retrieved data in the front-end when data is updated in the database?

Tags: mysql, rest, mobile, lamp

I'm building a mobile app where a pull-down gesture on the UI initiates an update of existing data/posts (also retrieves new posts if there are any, but that's not the point here). The server is stateless meaning there is no sessions.

If the posts have been updated in the database, how do I let the front-end know which posts need to be updated? Only way I could think of is to send a list of ids of all retrieved posts to the server, and have it check if any of the posts have been modified since the time fetched.

This however seems quiet inefficient as the users might have stacked up hundreds of posts in some extreme cases, and it's most likely that only few or none of the posts need to be updated. Issuing hundreds of db requests could be a huge overhead.

Answer (score 0):

There are at least 2 ways of doing this

1. Long Polling

   - client requests server for new information.
   - the server keeps the connection open until there is some new data to send.
   - once the server gets data, it sends this to the client and connection is closed.
   - the client then sends a new request for information.
   - This is a continuous process.
2. WebSockets

   - Create a websocket connection, keep it open.
   - The server pushes any updates as and when they come.

Problems with both situations

- May take a significant amount of time to have production ready implementations.
- Both them will require the server to be aware of any change in the database. This can be tricky as well